# Follow button does not work when reviewing a question or answer

Tags: bug

Title explains.

Pressing the "follow" button under a question or answer in the review section does nothing. I tested this both in the "late answers" and "first posts" section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug, see this Meta Stack Exchange question: [Unable to follow while in Review Queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350648/295232)
It has the [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) tag so they're going to do something about it, but apparently they're not in a hurry since that happened three months ago.

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking at all kinds of stuff this morning trying to see if it has been around. Guess my Google-Fu is not up to the task today ;-)